# How to add an event listener for an 'active' element

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have an event listener that is listening for a `click` event inside of a media query, if when the window is under `500px`. Likewise I have one that is listening for a `click` event if the window is wider than `500px`.

Once the buttons have been clicked within both states, the code works as I would like. However I have the following issue I would like to solve:

When the window is smaller than `500px` and the button is clicked it displays the content as required, though when the window is dragged to be wider than `500px`, the button then needs to be clicked again to show the content.

As I say this works fine once buttons have been clicked when the window is wider than `500px` and then again under `500px`, the correct content shows when the window is dragged back and forth.

What I would like to know is how to do the following:

When the button is clicked when the window is under `500px` and then dragged out, the corresponding content is displayed without having to press the button again. I also want this to be the case when the window is wider than `500px` and dragged to below this value.

Please see the JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tdmitchell/ztwqr9bo/7/)

Is there a way to somehow make an eventlistener for the element that has already been clicked and do it this way?

```
//Start listing variables for use in array.
var art1 = document.getElementById("article1");
var button1 = document.getElementById("btn1");

var art2 = document.getElementById("article2");
var button2 = document.getElementById("btn2");

var art3 = document.getElementById("article3");
var button3 = document.getElementById("btn3");

var articleArray = [art1, art2, art3];
var buttonArray = [button1, button2, button3];

function mediaQuery(x) {
  //If window is under 500px in width.
  if (x.matches) {
    //Begin accordion code
    var initAccordion = function(accordionElement) {
      function handlePanelClick(event) {
        showPanel(event.currentTarget);
      }

      function showPanel(panel) {
        var expandedPanel = accordionElement.querySelector(".active");
        if (expandedPanel) {
          expandedPanel.classList.remove("active");
        }
        panel.classList.add("active");
      }

      var allPanelElements = accordionElement.querySelectorAll(".panel");
      for (var y = 0; y < allPanelElements.length; y++) {
        allPanelElements[y].addEventListener("click", handlePanelClick);
      }
      //showPanel(allPanelElements[0]);
    }
    initAccordion(document.getElementById("contentWrapper"));

  } else { // If window if is over 500px in width.  
    //Begin button code.
    var createfunc = function(i) {
      return function() {
        document.getElementById("fillMe").innerHTML = articleArray[i].innerHTML;
      };
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < articleArray.length; i++) {
      let button = buttonArray[i];
      button.addEventListener("click", createfunc(i));
    }
  }
}

//Declare media query and add listener.
var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 500px)")
mediaQuery(x) // Call listener function at run time
x.addListener(mediaQuery) // Attach listener function on state changes
```

Comment: Rather than using a selector for each element and then storing them in a array, why don't you just assign them with a `class` name and change the selector?

Comment: @NewToJS This doesn't solve the issue though however.

Comment: You should listen for `window.onresize` and as soon as you catch transition from 501px to 500px you should simulate the clicking (or directly call the corresponding click handler) of the button for 500px. As soon as you catch transition from 500px to 501px - you should simulate the clicking of the other button.

Comment: Or have the button show both, but have them styled with via css media tags so that only the appropriate one shows for the correct screen size. That way css takes care of it for you and you don't need to add extra event listeners.

Comment: @KoolTRaps Correct, it doesn't fix the current issue but it does help clean up the source code from duplicating functions and make it easier to work with. This is why I have posted it as a comment not as a solution/answer.